# Problemas con Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

eh creado un sistema de gestión (ya instalado en un equipo), pero al momento de ver los reportes de dicho sistema, el sistema se cierra solo. utilice visualStudio 2015.

Comment: Has instalado en los equipos el crystal reporta?

Comment: Si, instalado sin ningún inconveniente

Comment: Si, instalado sin ningún inconveniente

Comment: algún error te dara, no? puedes decir cual? a parte del crystal reports que más has utilizado?

Comment: No muestra el error simplemente el sistema se cierra solo. utilice sql server 2014 y para los diseños MahApps.metro

Comment: Prueba a poner un try y catch en el programa desde que mandas crear el informe, a ver si hay muestra algo, porque si no como no mires en el registro de eventos de Windows no se me ocurre nada mas